# weird sound clip plays randomly. how to track/find it. was I hacked?

Tags: adb, notifications, audio, resource-monitoring, samsung-galaxy-note-8

Samsung Note 8 running Android b. 9  here is a screenshot of SW info:

[image]

My Android is playing weird 5-10 sec sound clip at random times.  It sounds like a combo of a hippo and then a slot machine paying out winnings.

But I can't figure out where the sound is coming from.  I've turned off notifications for all apps, and even made the default android notification SILENT.

But, it's still happening several times a day.  Is there any way /software I could install to watch the OS and figure out /teach where this is coming from... Or at least where it's stored so I can at least delete it.

I'm worried it might be some malware.  But I've scanned using lookout several times.

### UPDATE:

per Suggestion, I installed/used ADB on my MacOS Catalina & got some info:

1. first took care of brew:

   - `brew update`
   - `brew upgrade`
   - `brew cleanup`
   - `brew doctor`
2. installed ADB on my Mac:

   - `brew install android-platform-tools`
3. checked to see if ADB could see my phone, ran `adb devices` ==> actually got a weird error the first time:

   > ```
   >    adb server version (36) doesn't match this client (41); killing...
   >    * daemon started successfully
   >    
   >    List of devices attached
   >    ce071827a99a952b057e  device
   > ```
4. ***somehow*** fixed this, by doing nothing more than running the following commands a few times:

   - `adb`
   - `adb devices`
   - `which adb`
   - `adb devices`
   - `whereis adb`
5. ***After that***, I tried `adb devices` again, this time I got:

   > ```
   >    List of devices attached
   >    ce071827a99a952b057e  device
   > ```
6. then ran `adb shell dumpsys audio`  ==> huge dump, so trimmed it - with a few pre-steps in case I was going to have to run this a few times:
7. ran `adb shell` and got this (Android OS shell?) prompt: **`greatqlte:/ $`** ==> then ran to rim results/narrow the time a bit:

   1. **`greatqlte:/ $`** `dumpsys audio | grep "04-28 18:0."`

      ```
      04-28 18:00:02:105 requestAudioFocus() from uid/pid 10009/6846 clientId=android.media.AudioManager@5492af0 callingPack=com.android.systemui req=3 flags=0x0 sdk=28
      04-28 18:00:04:680 abandonAudioFocus() from uid/pid 10009/6846 clientId=android.media.AudioManager@5492af0
      04-28 18:00:01:954 new player piid:107767 uid/pid:10009/6846 type:android.media.MediaPlayer attr:AudioAttributes: usage=USAGE_UNKNOWN content=CONTENT_TYPE_UNKNOWN flags=0x0 tags= bundle=null
      04-28 18:00:01:955 player piid:107767 new AudioAttributes:AudioAttributes: usage=USAGE_NOTIFICATION_EVENT content=CONTENT_TYPE_UNKNOWN flags=0x0 tags= bundle=null
      04-28 18:00:01:959 player piid:107767 has OP_PLAY_AUDIO:true in uid:10009
      04-28 18:00:02:611 player piid:107767 state:started uid:10009
      04-28 18:00:02:617 releasing player piid:107727
      04-28 18:00:04:671 player piid:107767 state:stopped uid:10009
      04-28 18:02:31:090 new player piid:107775 uid/pid:1000/3362 type:android.media.MediaPlayer attr:AudioAttributes: usage=USAGE_UNKNOWN content=CONTENT_TYPE_UNKNOWN flags=0x0 tags= bundle=null
      04-28 18:02:31:151 player piid:107775 new AudioAttributes:AudioAttributes: usage=USAGE_NOTIFICATION content=CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION flags=0x0 tags= bundle=null
      04-28 18:02:31:152 player piid:107775 has OP_PLAY_AUDIO:true in uid:1000
      04-28 18:02:31:221 player piid:107775 state:started uid:1000
      04-28 18:02:32:923 player piid:107775 state:stopped uid:1000
      04-28 18:02:32:926 releasing player piid:107775
      04-28 18:05:46:607 new player piid:107783 uid/pid:1000/3362 type:android.media.MediaPlayer attr:AudioAttributes: usage=USAGE_UNKNOWN content=CONTENT_TYPE_UNKNOWN flags=0x0 tags= bundle=null
      04-28 18:05:46:685 player piid:107783 new AudioAttributes:AudioAttributes: usage=USAGE_NOTIFICATION content=CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION flags=0x0 tags= bundle=null
      04-28 18:05:46:687 player piid:107783 has OP_PLAY_AUDIO:true in uid:1000
      04-28 18:05:46:822 player piid:107783 state:started uid:1000
      04-28 18:05:48:580 player piid:107783 state:stopped uid:1000
      04-28 18:05:48:596 releasing player piid:107783
      04-28 18:05:52:569 player piid:106799 state:started uid:1000
      ```
   2. then I looked for packages that matched?? with:
      **`greatqlte:/ $`** `cmd package list packages -U | grep "10009"`

      ```
      package:com.samsung.android.app.aodservice uid:10009
      package:com.sec.android.easyonehand uid:10009
      package:com.sec.android.cover.ledcover uid:10009
      package:com.samsung.desktopsystemui uid:10009
      package:com.android.systemui uid:10009
      ```

Comment: Note down the time whenever that sound plays. Then setup [tag:adb] and run `adb shell dumpsys audio`. Look under Playback Activity section in the dump. (Better if you post the output in the question). You would find some uid/pid lines. They can help you out narrow the problem. Write down all UIDs closer to the time you noted. Next step is to find out which UID belongs to which app. Run the command `adb shell cmd package list packages -U`. It would list package name and next to them, their UID. Find which UID belongs to which package there and report back.

Comment: @Firelord If the app that causes this is just aiming in generating money by playing ads invisible in the background then it would only misuse network access and CPU resources but I would still call it a malware.

Comment: @Robert valid point. I have removed my incorrect comment.

Comment: You guys are awesome... Thanks. I just saw these comments now. Will try these steps tonight. OOC @firelord why didn't you answer the question as opposed to only comment on it?

Comment: @FlakDiNenno because I like to answer only when I'm certain it has worked for the asker. If my comment helps solving your problem, let me know. I'll post it as a proper answer. :)

Comment: ok... so first new thing/problem... is I somehow got rid of the sound... BUT, it's now playing whatever default sound I've set and I can't figure out what's playing it.  I will post the dumps in the question. ok, thanks!

Comment: @Firelord, please take a look.  I probably need to include more... but I the logs are really long

Comment: @FlakDiNenno can you post the full dump the next time that sound plays? Here's how to capture the dump: `adb shell dumpsys audio > audio_dump.txt`. This command would dump the text in a text file named `audio_dump.txt`. Share this text file with us using pastebin.com. The location of text file is the folder from which you ran adb executable.

Comment: Ok. Will do tomorrow. Thnx again